# How can I apply the same shop filter to all WooCommerce pages in WordPress?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

can you help me, please!
I want applied same shop filters for all woocommerce page with same style,
so, I tried to create a new widget with same shop filters but it shows different!

I use UX Blocks with flastsome theme, any advice?!

Answer (score 0):

```
function apply_shop_filter_to_all_pages($query) {
    if (is_woocommerce() && is_shop() && !is_admin()) {
        // Apply your shop filter here
    }
}
add_action('pre_get_posts', 'apply_shop_filter_to_all_pages');
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?